# Ruby Methods and Params Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop

I have a general questions about how to treat params on a method. Let's say, we have a method that receives a number and multiplies it by 2.

```
def multiplier(num)
  num*2
end
```

What happens when num is nil? Who is responsible to handle the error? The method itself or the one who calls the method? What is considered the best oop practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to OOP in any way, because it applies to other paradigms as well. That said, there are different schools of thought about the problem. Which one is the "best" depends on who you're talking to.

One is "defensive programming everywhere". This means each method is responsible for rigorous checks of its input.

Another is "caller is responsible for providing correct data".

Another is what I call a "security perimeter": rigorous checks only when we deal with external input, but once data is "inside of the system", it can be trusted.

And anything in between.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was curious to find out what others believe on the matter, as i often encounter different approaches on the code i review. P.S. Your are right. It is neither a ruby or oop question.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers (@sergio-tulentsev, @Зелёный). And there is another thing to consider.

In a lot of cases it is a good practice not to expect an object of particular type, but an object which acts like a particular type. I mean, in your case, the method could expect not only a number to be passed as a parameter, but any object that could be treated like a number. That would not only make your method more powerful, but also solve the `nil` problem. Of course it depends on your needs.

The method version I am talking about might look like this:

```
def multiplier(num)
  # trying to convert whatever is passed to a number
  num.to_f * 2
end
```

In the case of `nil` it will return `0.0`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I think it depends on the business logic of the app. Trying to convert an object to what you except will work (i.e. num.to_f) may hide a problem you haven't predicted.